# Problem: re-rendering vue instance when data is changed by a call-back inside a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm developing a app with electron using vue.js as a standalone libray (no CLI envolved) and it get a pretty wird re-rendering behavior when I change data by a call-back of a electron method inside a vue method (rendering on a v-for). I show a simplified code:

```html
<div class="list-item" v-for="(filePath, index) in playlistArray">
   <div class="audio-file-index"> {{ index + 1 }} </div>
   <div class="audio-file-name"> {{ filePath }} </div>
</div>
```

```
const { remote } = require('electron');

let vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    playlistArray: ['', '', '', '', '']
    // could just '= Array(5)' but i need '' elements so the v-for renders 5 
    // empty divs right away
  },
  methods: {
    addAudioFile() {

      remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({ // electron.remote method to let user select files

        //... doesn't metter, just a options object....

      }, (pathArray) => {
         // pathArray returns a array with all paths selected by the user

         let j = 0;
         for(i = 0; i < this.playlistArray.length; i++) {
            if(this.playlist[i] == '') {
               this.playlistArray[i] = pathArray[i + j];
               j++;
            }
         }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Ok so when the user select audio files the divs show the path and (index + 1) of each path.

First thing I don't get: after the first call of addAudioFile( ), all the ' ' elements of playlistArray turns to undefined, so I had to change the if statemant to:

```
if(this.playlistArray[i] == '' || this.playlistArray[i] == undefined)
```

Why is it changing? (If the array has a element with a truthy string it doesen't change to undefined). But ok...

The wird behavior: v-for doesn't re-render when playlistArray is changed... but...If I toogle the developers tools, close it, and click anywhere in my app the re-rendering works (?).

I changed the code using another help method and a help variable:

```
...

let vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    playlistArray: ['', '', '', '', '']
  },
  methods: {
    addAudioFile() {

      remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({

        ...

      }, (pathArray) => {
         let j = 0;
         let newPlaylistArray = [];

         for(i = 0; i < this.playlistArray.length; i++) {
            if(this.playlist[i] == '' || this.playlistArray[i] == undefined) {
               newPlaylistArray[i] = pathArray[0 + j];
               j++;
            }
            else newPlaylistArray[i] = this.playlistArray[i] || '';
         }
         this.updatePlaylist(newPlaylistArray);
      })
    },

     updatePlaylist(playlist) {
        this.playlistArray = playlist;
     }
  }
})
```

... and now it works properly. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is because of reactivity. As the documentation says:

> Vue **cannot** detect the following changes to an array:
>
> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
>   `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
>
> [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

---

To make your first example work, you can try the `splice` or `set` methods:

```js
for(i = 0; i < this.playlistArray.length; i++) {
  if(this.playlist[i] == '') {
    this.playlistArray.splice(i, 1, pathArray[i + j])
    // or
    this.$set(this.playlistArray, i, pathArray[i + j])
    j++;
  }
}
```

---

Note: you use this condition `if(this.playlist[i] == '')`. Where `playlist` property comes from ? Do you mean `playlistArray` instead ?

Comment: Thanks! It works. And yes, I made a mistake here, I meant playlistArray.